# How to bind hammer.js to multiple ids

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, hammer.js

On a page I have several bootstrap carousels, and I want them to be working on swipe. To do that, I use `hammer.js`. It is not a problem to bind `hammer.js` to one element, for example:

```
var swipeElement = document.getElementById('carousel');

  if (typeof(swipeElement) != 'undefined' && swipeElement != null) {
    var hammertime = new Hammer(swipeElement, {
      recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Swipe, {direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL}]
      ],
      cssProps: {
        userSelect: "", contentZooming: ""
      }
    });

    hammertime.on('swiperight', function () {
      $('.left.carousel-control').click();
    });

    hammertime.on('swipeleft', function () {
      $('.right.carousel-control').click();
    });

  }
```

That's working. But I have several carousels wit ids: `carousel_1`, `carousel_2`, etc. How can I initialize `hammer.js`, without writing code for each id separately? Thanks.

**EDIT**:

I was trying to do this:

```
  var swipeElements = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-inner');
  for(var i = 0; i < swipeElements.length; i++) {
    if (typeof(swipeElements[i]) != 'undefined' && swipeElements[i] != null) {
      var elementId = document.getElementById(swipeElements[i].id);
      var hammertime = new Hammer(elementId, {
        recognizers: [
          [Hammer.Swipe, {direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL}]
        ],
        cssProps: {
          userSelect: "", contentZooming: ""
        }
      });

      hammertime.on('swiperight', function () {
          $(elementId).parent().children('.left.carousel-control').click();
      });

      hammertime.on('swipeleft', function () {
          $(elementId).parent().children('.right.carousel-control').click();
      });

    }
  }
```

But still doesn't help. If I substitute:

```
hammertime.on('swipeleft', function () {
    $(elementId).parent().children('.right.carousel-control').click();
});
```

for:

```
hammertime.on('swipeleft', function () {
   $('.right.carousel-control').click();
});
```

It will trigger all my carousels on the page. If I swipe to the right, all the other carousels are swiping to the right too. I'm confused...

**EDIT**: for some reason `$(elementId)` has value `carousel_6`, but it is placed into the loop, so it has to have values from `carousel_0` to `carousel_6`

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('[selector matching all elements]'), and then `forEach` on that array?

Comment: Doing: `var a = document.querySelectorAll('div.carousel-inner.thumb-inner')` and then `Array.isArray(a)` gives me `false`. So, how can I use `forEach`?

Comment: It returns a NodeList, which has `forEach` method as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a distinct class for each wrapper and then iterate through it with jQuery.

```
$('.carousel').each(function(i, el){
    // el is the actual DOM element
    // we save a jQuery wrapped version here in the closure so that
    // it is available to callbacks.
    var $el = $(el);
    var hammertime = new Hammer(el, {
      recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Swipe, {direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL}]
      ],
      cssProps: {
        userSelect: "", contentZooming: ""
      }
    });

    hammertime.on('swiperight', function () {
      $el.find('.left.carousel-control').click();
    });

    hammertime.on('swipeleft', function () {
      $el.find('.right.carousel-control').click();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your issue is below. The code added above didn't work for me.

```js
; (function ($, window, document) {
    'use strict';
    var $sliders = $('.carousel');
    var hammer = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $sliders.length; i++) {
        var slider = $sliders[i];
        hammer[i] = new Hammer($sliders.get(i));
        $(slider).find('img').each((index, elem) => {
            $(elem).prop('draggable', false);
        });
        $(slider).carousel();
        $(slider).find(".carousel-control-prev").click((e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(slider).carousel("prev");
        });
        $(slider).find(".carousel-control-next").click((e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(slider).carousel("next");
        });
        hammer[i].on("panleft panright", (e) => {            
            e.preventDefault();
            var slider = $(e.target).closest(".carousel");
            if (e.type == 'panleft') $(slider).carousel("next");
            if (e.type == 'panright') $(slider).carousel("prev");
        });
        $(slider).find('.carousel-indicators li').click((e) => {
            $(slider).carousel($(e.target).data('slide-to'));
        });
    }
})(jQuery, window, document);
```